# How to download file from Firebase storage to custom folder?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have been searching all day long even here on stack overflow but none of the code seems to work. I want to download a file(s) from FirebaseStorage to a custom folder on internal/external storage but no luck whatsoever.

my code:

```
private void downloadfile() {

    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    ref = mStorageRef.child("song.mp3");

    try {
        File localFile = File.createTempFile("song", "mp3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Folder");
        // Create direcorty if not exists
    if(!storagePath.exists()) {
        storagePath.mkdirs();
    }

    final File myFile = new File(storagePath,"song.mp3");

    mStorageRef.getFile(myFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Local temp file has been created
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create the path to the file

```
String sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String filePath = sdCardPath + "<YOUR_PATH_LIKE_/Downloads>" + "Filename";
```

2.) Create the file:

```
File directory = new File(filePath);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply can you please be more specific as in what should I remove from my code (I am still a java noob)

Comment: I'd say the that localFile is unused so you can remove that, secondly, you can try to replace your myFile section with my code.